# datatable ajax send data values in array

Tags: ajax, datatable, codeigniter-2

i tried using ajax/datable/codeigniter and i want to send my data in post like array data for example (search['value'] = searched_key).

```
        function fetch_vtourdata( is_range_search, minPrice = '', maxPrice = '', minSurface = '', maxSurface = '', minNbRoom = '', maxNbRoom = '', searched_key = '')
        {
            var dataTable = $('#data_tableVtoursList').DataTable({
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "order": [],
                "ajax":{
                    url: "../../website/userVtourTable",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { 'user_id': user_id,
                        // 1 = name of POST, 2 = values
                            is_range_search:is_range_search,
                            minPrice:minPrice,
                            maxPrice:maxPrice,
                            minSurface:minSurface,
                            maxSurface:maxSurface,
                            minNbRoom:minNbRoom,
                            maxNbRoom:maxNbRoom,
                            search[{
                                'value':searched_key
                            }] 
                          }
                },
                "columnDefs" : [
                    {
                        "target": [0, 3, 4],
                        "orderable": false,
                    }
                ]
            });

            $('#search').keyup(function(){
                dataTable.search($(this).val()).draw();
            });
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXseD.png)

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: search[{
                                'value':searched_key
                            }]
not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my result is same than my first post just change :

```
search [{
   'value' : searched_key
}]
```

by

```
searched_key: searched_key
```

define in your controller method :

```
if ( isset( $_POST['searched_key'] ) && !empty( $_POST['searched_key'] ) ) {
     $_POST['search']['value'] = $_POST['searched_key'];    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the data table function and place the `datable` dunction inside your javascript below your html, seperate the ajax data inside a controller

Could you tell more details about your problem ?
like this

```
 var oTable = $('#example').DataTable({
        "ajax": "<?php echo base_url('dashboard/show_karyawan'); ?>",
        "bDestroy": true,
        "columns": [
           {
              "data": "id",
              render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                  return meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1;
                 }
          },
            { "data": "NIP" },
            { "data": "nama" },
            { "data":"jabatan"},
          {
           "data": null, 
           "sDefaultContent": '<a href="" class="editor_view">view</a> / <a href="" class="editor_remove">Delete</a>'
          }

        ]
    });
```

I will suggest you use the newest Datatables, since there some function that wont work with the tutorial of datatables nowadays.

[Datables ver. 1.10](https://www.datatables.net/download/index)

Comment: my problem is just send data to get $_POST['search']['value'] in my controller method but it's resolved, i just send my data like this :"data": {searched_jey:searched_key} and define in my method $_post['search']['value'] = $_post['searched_key'];

Comment: @ITS could you upload the result you have made ? for the future viewers